# shorter and easier way to code hide/show divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easier and shorter way to code a way to show and hide divs without having to represent each line as a show or hide?

```html
function startOver() {
    $('.box1').hide();
 $('.box2').hide();
 $('#box3').hide();
 $('.box4').show();
 $('.box5').show();
 $('.box6').show();
 $('.box7').show();
 $(".aboveDiv").html("Insert Text");
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [multiple-selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) using `,` of jquery

```
function startOver() {
    $('.box1, .box2, #box3').hide();
    $('.box4, .box5, .box6, .box7').show();
    $(".aboveDiv").html("Insert Text");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can select more than one class using a `,`:-

```
$('.box1, .box2, #box3').hide();
$('.box4, .box5, .box6, .box7').show();
$(".aboveDiv").html("Insert Text");
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers for sure give the right answer, though from a javascript perspective, you might want to create a new class that is called something like box-hidable, and then give this class to each box you want to hide (e.g.)

```
<div class="box1 box-hidable"></div>
<div class="box2 box-hidable"></div>
(etc)
```

Then in your script call

`$(".box-hidable").hide();`

This allows you to factor your class structure nicely, and make your code more readable.

Comment: Was just about to post this. This is the cleanest way in my opinion.

Comment: This does kindof force you to create a new class for each different showing / hiding scenario, which is the only negative side. Though you're creating less classes anyway.

Comment: yeah unfortunately, I can't use global classes as I am intertwining a bit more code

Comment: Maybe you should see if you can revisit the intertwining code then, sounds like it's all tightly coupled

Answer (score 1):

As others have said doing below will help you

$('.box1, .box2, #box3').hide();
$('.box4, .box5, .box6, .box7').show();

but if you have group of such elements which toggle their status then you can apply different classes to both group i.e.

'.box1, .box2, #box3' with adding class class_a
'.box4, .box5, .box6, .box7' with adding class class_b

and then you can easily toggle

$('.class_a').hide();
$('.class_b').show();

Answer (score 0):

Global classes to the ones you need can also work.

```
function startOver() {
    $('.hidebox').hide();
    $('.showbox').show();
    $(".aboveDiv").html("Insert Text");
}

<div class="box1 hidebox"></div>
<div class="box2 hidebox"></div>
<div class="box3 hidebox"></div>
<div class="box4 showbox"></div>
<div class="box5 showbox"></div>
<div class="box6 showbox"></div>
```